# How to compress files in CakePHP and serve it as download

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to zip compress files according to what the admin want and then admin will be able to download the files he selected in one zip files.. Is there any plugin/component to compress these files and serve it as download to user?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ZIP extension for PHP that you could use.

Examples of usage here:  www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php